# how to make arc shape in box2d for iphone

Tags: iphone, box2d

hey guys i m looking for how some one can achieve the curve or concave shape in box2d for iphone i m stuck with this... Thanks in Advance...
Umer Sufyan.

Answer (score 1):

Use polygons with small segments.

Comment: umer, imagine you had to draw a pear with only straight edges. How would you do it?